# zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Tags: python, zlib

I'm trying to decompress this base64, and am getting this exception what's wrong with the code?

```
import zlib
import base64

b = "kxcp+3ky2c95u2rhHvGq6t12rh64MhjvC3tujkONnrQ4VIh2jr3FlLudiQJzeTLN"

print(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b)))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lcardoso/Projetos/stalkers/busca_nfe_incompleta/teste.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b)))
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Comment: Well.Your data is incorrect. When you try to b64decode your b the result is `b"\x93\x17)\xfby2\xd9\xcfy\xbbj\xe1\x1e\xf1\xaa\xea\xddv\xae\x1e\xb82\x18\xef\x0b{n\x8eC\x8d\x9e\xb48T\x88v\x8e\xbd\xc5\x94\xbb\x9d\x89\x02sy2\xcd"` And this is not correctly zlib compressed data. That is why zlib can't decompress it. `zlip.decomress` is able to decompress only correctly compressed data.

Comment: Is there any way I could encrypt this base64 I figured it would be a zip?

Comment: I don't really understand. Where did you get your data (`b = "kxcp+3ky2c95u2rhHvGq6t12rh64MhjvC3tujkONnrQ4VIh2jr3FlLudiQJzeTLN"`) from?

Comment: I get this data because I'm developing a crawler and I have to understand what this base64 is in order to be able to replicate.

Comment: The binary data that results from the Base-64 decoding of that string is not a zlib stream, nor does it even contain valid deflate data. It's not raw deflate, gzip, or zip.

Comment: It's okay, I'll try other things then, thank you.